# restar valor de variables distintas 2 campos de 2 tablas distintas usando php

Tags: php

Tengo 2 tablas

una ticket

que contiene un dato

```
  `prioridad` set('300','400','500','600','700','800','900','1000','1500','2000','2500','3000','3500','4000','4500','5000','5500','6000','6500','7000','7500','8000','8500','9000','9500','10000') NOT NULL,
```

y otra usuario

que tiene un dato cartera

```
  `cartera` int(6) NOT NULL,
```

Info
Uso el Set para poder mostrar un error si el dato ingresado en ese campo
no es igual a alguno de ellos

tengo una función para insertar datos en mi tabla ticket , pero no entiendo como hacer para restar 2 valores usando la otra tabla.
quiero restar el valor que obtenga en propiedad a el valor que hay en cartera.
Hay problemas si intento restar esos dos tipos de datos?

```
    function addTicket($conexion){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO ticket (id_usuario, tipo_solicitud, prioridad, titulo, observacion, status, fecha_creacion, hora_creacion)
                                 VALUES ('".$this->idUsuario."', '".$this->tipoSolicitud."', '".$this->prioridad."', '".$this->titulo."',
                                         '".$this->observacion."', '".$this->status."', '".$this->fecha."', '".$this->hora."')")
                                 or die("Error insertando nuevo Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una select dentro de values.

```
INSERT INTO col_1 ( val_1, val_otra_tabla ) 
VALUES('val_1', (SELECT val_2 FROM tabla_2 WHERE val_2 = x))
```

Con la select ya puedes hacer la resta de los datos que necesites.